# REGEX serach and replace HTTP RC's in logs

Tags: http, replace

I have a log file with HTTP and other return codes. The blank between the numeric return code and the text that describes the RC is causing me problems normalizing this data for parsing. 
Here's a few examples of the data:
rc(200 OK)
rc(403 Unauthorized)
rc()

I want to retain both the numeric RC and the RC text and I want to change the blank to a dash(-). So given the data above, I want this:
rc(200-OK)
rc(403-Unauthorized)
rc()

I think this match pattern works: rc(\d{3}\s but I'm sick to death of sed complaining about everything I try :(

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick.  It works by capturing the groups on either side of the space you want to replace, then puts them back but with a dash instead.

```
$ sed -E 's/(rc\([0-9]+)(\s+?)([a-zA-Z0-9]+?\))/\1-\3/g' x.log
rc(200-OK) rc(403-Unauthorized) rc()
$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could capture `rc(` followed by 3 digits `[0-9]{3}` in a capturing group followed by matching one or more times a whitespace character `\s+`.

Then replace with that capturing group followed by a `-`. Use global `/g` to replace all occurrences.

```
$ echo "rc(200 OK) rc(403 Unauthorized) rc()" | sed -E 's/(rc\([0-9]{3})\s+/\1-/g'
rc(200-OK) rc(403-Unauthorized) rc()
```

**Match** `(rc\([0-9]{3})\s+`

**Replace** `\1-`

**Demo** http://rextester.com/VQKA81573